# Determination of connected set

Tags: general-topology

Prove or disprove: $\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x^2+y^3\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}\rbrace$ is disconnected with the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: Hint:$f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ $f(x,y)=x^2+y^3$ is continous function

Comment: @ Senore: I also tried that but failed. Please provide some more hint.

Comment: do you know Image of a connected set under a continous map must be connected? $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But we are not finding image of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, isn't it?

Comment: @SucharitaDeb what can you tell about the sets $x^2+y^3<2$ and $x^2+y^3>2$

Comment: @SucharitaDeb: Combine the comments from Clark & Seonore to get a contradiction. Or note that the inverse image of a disconnected set under a continuous function must itself be disconnected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just fleshing out the details in the comments.

Let $A=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x^2+y^3\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}\}$ and note that $f\colon A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f=g|_A$ where $g\colon\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \colon (x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^3$ is continuous as it is the restriction of a continuous function to a subset with the subspace topology. The image of $f$ is the set of irrational numbers which is a disconnected set and so $A$ can not be connected as the image of a connected space is a connected subset of the codomain.